# Java is not recognized as an internal or external command in vba inside shell in a batch

Tags: java, vba, windows-7, batch

Every time I try to call the java function from the shell function in vba or from the batch file from the shell function in vba it says that Java is not a recognized command. Though I can do this straight up inside of a cmd window. My question is how do I allow this?
-Using Windows 7 and through Excel VBA

Comment: Care to show us an example?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to specify the full path to the java executable in VBA rather than just the word 'java'. For example on my Windows 7 machine it is as below, yours may be different

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java
```

Comment: Then it says that C:\Program is not a recognizable command...

Comment: Ok you need to wrap it in speach marks, i'm not too familiar with VBA so you may need to escape the speach marks too. e.g. "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java" or \"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java\"

Comment: This works, until a new version of Java is installed. Why doesn't VBA use the PATH to search for Java?

Answer (score 0):

This either tells me that either Java is not installed or it is not in your path. 
In case Java is not installed, you can install the most recent version of the JRE. 
However in case it is installed, ensure that the Java executable is in your system's path. Also, you can find the directory it is installed in and then using the full path to that directory.

Comment: I have installed Java and it still gives me this error after permanently setting the PATH variable to both the SDK and the java

Comment: Did you try with the double \\ for windows path- something like C:\\

Answer (score 0):

Got it solved like most things if you just force it then it should work but yeah. Most likely if this program gives me any more trouble I'll open this thread again. Thanks for the help.

I ran a batch file that basically did the same thing but I set the class path for the run as **C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin** so that it was forced to see java rather than me manually doing it in the environment variables. Honestly this is a Windows 7 problem so it might have been solved some other way. Sorry I can't provide anymore information.

Comment: How did you solve it? Please post in your answer, and then accept your own answer, so that the question can be removed from the unsolved list.